# Replace double quotes with single quotes

Tags: double, quotes

I would like to change "1964" to '1964'
I have tried all combination but no success

```
       string rowString = "1964";

        var myString = "1964";
        var myStrin = Regex.Replace(myString, @"[\""]", "'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        string y = rowString.Trim('"');
        string yy = rowString.Replace("\"", String.Empty);

        var yvc = rowString.Replace("\"", String.Empty);
        rowString = rowString.Replace("\"", "'");
        rowString.Trim('"', '\'', ' ');
        rowString = rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
        var somestring = rowString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
        rowString = rowString.Replace("'", "''");
        string strgs = rowString.Replace("'", "''");
        string strgg = rowString.Replace("\"", "'");
        string strgod = rowString.Replace("\"", "'");
        string strgodd = rowString.Replace("\"", "").Replace("'", "");
```

Comment: Can't you just do   var newString= "'" +myString  + "'"

Comment: Thanks this is solution!

Comment: pls don't forget to upvote and mark as accepted  !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do `var newString= "'" +myString + "'"`